# Как удалить лишние символы в телефонном номере?

Tags: javascript

Есть вот такой вот текст задачи:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript" TYPE="text/javascript">
function prepare(form) {
    var str = form.phone.value
    var re1 = new RegExp(/[-()/\\]/g)
    str = str.replace(re1,'')
    var re2 = new RegExp(/^\d{7}$/)
    if(!re2.test(str)) {
        alert('Пожалуйста, проверьте правильность телефонного номера')
        form.phone.focus()
        form.phone.select()
        return false
    }
    form.phone.value = str
    alert('Телефонный номер верен')
    return true
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Его нужно оформить в готовую страницу (открыл ослом и проверил номер из 7-ми символов), от этого зависит мой экзамен, только в моем исполнении он естественно не работает.

Comment: Firebug запускал?

Comment: нет, но код проверялся в готовой странице (со всеми Body/head/title и проч.), которую и надо получить, в осле преподавателем.

Comment: Что не работает конкретно? Запусти под Firebug-ом (это такой расширение в Firefox-е), он тебе укажет ошибки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title> 
        </title> 
        <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript" TYPE="text/javascript"> 
            function prepare(form) { 
                var str = form.phone.value 
                var re1 = new RegExp(/[-()/\\]/g) 
                str = str.replace(re1,'') 
                var re2 = new RegExp(/^\d{7}$/) 
                if(!re2.test(str)) { 
                    alert('Пожалуйста, проверьте правильность телефонного номера'); 
                    form.phone.focus(); 
                    form.phone.select(); 
                    return false
                } 
                form.phone.value = str 
                alert('Телефонный номер верен') 
                return true
            } 
        </SCRIPT> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <form> 
            <input type="text" name="phone" /> 
            <button onclick="prepare(this.form)">ТЫНЦ</button> 
        </form> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Вот итог. ) Все, спасибо, закрыли тему. )

Answer (score 2):

Был такой вариант, но не успел запостить, пока тут все не поломалось. Плюс в том, что событие висит на form.onsubmit, что отлавливает любые способы отправки формы - как по нажатию на submit, так и простым энтером в поле ввода.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head><title></title>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
function prepare()  
{  
    var x = document.getElementById('phone');  
    var v = x.value;  
    v = v.replace(/\D/g, ''); //замена не-цифр  
    if(v.length != 7)  
    {  
        alert('Неправильный номер!');  
        return false;  
    }  
    alert(v + ' - правильный номер!');  
    return true;  
}  
</script>  
</head>  
<body>

<form method="post" action="#" onSubmit="return prepare();">  
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" /><input type="submit" value="test" />  
</form>

</body>  
</html>
```